# NSUnknownKeyExeption using firebase and NSobject

Tags: swift, firebase, nsunknownkeyexception

> 2018-12-30 15:01:23.228731+0200 iChat[51679:726127] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key username.'
>   (lldb)

Using firebase dictionary to setvalue for a key to NSobject class

```
import UIKit

class User: NSObject {
var email: String?
var username: String?
}
```

Function

```
func fetchUsers() {
    Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded) { (snap) in
        if let dictionary = snap.value as? [String : AnyObject]{
        let user = User()
            user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
            print(user.username)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-C inference has been changed in Swift 4. You have to add the `@objc` attribute to each property

```
class User: NSObject {
   @objc var email: String?
   @objc var username: String?
}
```

However `setValuesForKeys` is very *objective-c-ish*. There are better (and more light-weight) ways in Swift without the heavy ObjC runtime.

And why are both properties optional? Are users allowed without name and email?

Consider that with non-optionals the compiler will throw an error at **compile time** if you are going to pass `nil`.

Comment: There are better (and more light-weight) ways in Swift without the heavy ObjC runtime.  can you give an example in my case

Comment: The `Codable` protocol or for only a few properties an initializer which maps each value *manually*.